# Is the rewrite module activated for nginx in the Wordpress juju

Tags: juju, nginx, wordpress, mod-rewrite

Is the rewrite module activated for nginx in the Wordpress juju? When I change the permalink to anything other than default I get bad gateway.

rewrite is mandatory for buddypress to function properly. Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following to the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/wordpress` which seems to have fixed the issue.

```
# Wordpress permalinks
if (!-e $request_filename) {
 rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
 break;
}
```

Is this a good way to do it or does the charm have to be modified to include this?

Comment: Send me a mail (see my profile) and we'll just fix it in the charm (Or you can file a bug on the wordpress charm: https://launchpad.net/charms/+source/wordpress